# Unicode decoding error from json webpage

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-requests, python-3.4

As is the way of things, i'm having issues decoding some unicode in python

specifically, this webpage: xkcd.com/403/info.0.json

The relevant part is `Paul Erd\u00c5\u0091s!`

When i run it through the json decoder, the unicode gets decoded, but not using the correct codec

I'm currently using the one-liner:

```
requests.get("http://xkcd.com/403/info.0.json").json()["alt"][-12:]
```

which gets `'Paul ErdÅ\x91s!'` which is obviously not what i want

Any ideas as to what i can do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that JSON you'll need to encode to Latin-1 (since it transcodes bytes naively) and then decode from UTF-8.

**Twice. Because it's double-broken.**

```
>>> json.loads('"Erd\u00c3\u0085\u00c2\u0091s!"')
u'Erd\xc3\x85\xc2\x91s!'
>>> json.loads('"Erd\u00c3\u0085\u00c2\u0091s!"').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'Erd\xc5\x91s!'
>>> json.loads('"Erd\u00c3\u0085\u00c2\u0091s!"').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'Erd\u0151s!'
>>> print json.loads('"Erd\u00c3\u0085\u00c2\u0091s!"').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8').encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
Erdős!
```

Comment: wait, "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0151' in position 102: ordinal not in range(256)" on decoding the second time. any ideas?

Comment: oh, i see, it's because it's different(!) in the transcript from the alt-text.... -_-